# How to prevent entire user models from leaking up into the jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am currently working on the log in portion of my project but I am working with express, passport-local and mongoose. I have a set of routes:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index', { user : req.user, title : "Home" });
    });

    app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
        res.render('register', { });
    });

    app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
            Athlete.register(new Athlete({
            username: req.param('username'),
            firstName: req.param('firstName'),
            lastName: req.param('lastName'),
            dob: req.param('dob')
        }), req.param('password'), function(err, athlete) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.render('register');
            }    
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });

    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        res.render('login', { user : req.user.username });
    });

    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
    });

    app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
            res.redirect('/');
        });
    });};
```

I am currently able to sign in and sign out no problem and it displays my name as per the jade template using the `p= user.firstName` jade syntax. This though is burping up a object that contains a salt, hash, as well as the model values. This is clearly a huge security issue and I want to wrap my hear around what is going on between the route and the template. How can I prevent the entire user database object from coming up and which part of my code is causing the miscommunication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your user object won't leak as jade will be rendered on server side until you expose the secret information in your template. So passing extra information won't result in leaking.

Still if you want to restrict the entire user passing into jade, you can add a method in your user schema and call that method while using res.render.

```
userSchema.methods.getSafeUser = function() {
   var user = this;
   //filter user as per your requirements here.

   return user;
```

}

Then in your controller, use

```
res.render('index', { user : req.user.getSafeUser() });
```

Comment: Ok so even having my entire user db object go to jade as long as i do like user.username it will be complied on the server and only the rendered username will be displayed. So no magic tricks to access the rest of the json document client-side.

Comment: yes correct, only rendered html will be sent to client. you can accept the answer if it answered your question.